# OpenCart 2.3.x Extension menu missing

Tags: opencart, opencart2.x, opencart2.3

I am logged in as Top Admin and there is no Extension bar in the gray left side navigation. See this screen capture:

[image: screen capture of admin area]

I checked the database and there is a table called oc_extension in there with the following rows:

[image]

Any idea what I can do to get the Extension menu to show in this installation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It also looks like there are other bars missing.
 Besides 'Extensions' there is also 'Customers' and 'Marketing' that do not appear in your menu (see image below). 
As it appears that there is nothing wrong with your database, perhaps you want to check your user settings first.
Go to Admin => System => Users=> => User Groups and check if your user group (typically 'Administrator') has full access and modification rights. 
...In Admin => System => Users=> Users=> 'Your username' =>Edit-button)

you can verify or change to what group your account is registered 
If you are sure you have full access and modifcation rights then I would try to see if perhaps the file system is incomplete. If you installed the file system through FTP upload you might want to upload the files once more to add or complete components. If you installed using an auto-installer provided by your host I would delete this install and try again. If, in that case the problem persits,  contact your host and let them look into it
I hope these ideas can be put to use, let me know how things go if you like. Good luck!
Here's my menu, OC version 2.3.0.2.
 [image: Admin menu OC Version 2.3.0.2]

Comment: Thank you! The issue was indeed that I did not have the permissions set properly. I fixed those and now i can see all the tabs.

Comment: You're welcome! Happy to hear it was a simple and easy fix Thanks for replying,

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the user doesn't have permission to access those Menus. Please check the group to which the user is mapped with and then edit that group to assign permissions. Go to Users->User Groups and edit the "Administrator" group. On the next page click on "Select all" for "Access Permission" and "Modify Permission" checkbox groups.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. You were correct, the group permissions were not all checked off.